# How tornado authentication works?

Tags: python, tornado, tornado-redis

How authentication works in tornado with set_secure_cookie method?
where are these cookies get stored for multiple users ?
how can we authenticate each API calls inside the framework ?

Answer (score 3):

Cookies are just HTTP headers. Nothing special. Cookies work like this:

1. Browser sends a request to server. This can by any request, like a regular page request, or a login form submission. For this example, let's just talk about a login request.
2. Server will look at the submitted `username` and `password` and make sure they are correct. Then server will set a cookie on this browser so that it can later identify the user. To set a cookie, the server will send a header called `Set-Cookie` along with the response. It will look like this - `Set-Cookie: sessionId=username`.
3. When the browser will get the response, it will also notice that there's a `SET-COOKIE` header on the response. Now the browser will *save* this value somewhere on your computer, it doesn't matter. What matters is after this, whenever the browser will send the request to your server, it will also send this cookie in the request headers like this - `Cookie: sessionId=username`.
4. Next time, server will also notice the `Cookie` header in the request. And so, it will get the username of the logged in user from there.

And that is how cookies work.

---

Now to answer your questions:

> How authentication works in tornado with set_secure_cookie method?

You might have noticed a big security flaw in the above example. To identify the user we have set the `sessionId` value in plain text. Anyone can easily send a different username in the cookie and our server will treat them as that user. For example if Alice wants to hack Bob's account, all she has to do is send the session cookie like this - `Cookie: sessionId=bob`. And our server will treat Alice as Bob.

This is where the `set_secure_cookie` method comes in. It will set a signed token, instead of a plain username. Tornado will set signed cookies based on your `cookie_secret` setting value. This is secure because cookies are signed based on the `cookie_secret` which nobody knows accept you. The cookie will look like this - `sessionId=slsafj7987LJflsfslfljk68686sfj`. Now, Alice can't impersonate as Bob.

> where are these cookies get stored for multiple users ?

Nowhere. Since the cookies are signed, Tornado will decode the value from the signed cookies as the request comes in. For example if a cookie header looks like this - `Cookie: sessionId=alksjfl98798yfaslkdjf`. Tornado will decode this - `alksjfl98798yfaslkdjf` value to extract the encoded username. It happens on-the-fly.

> how can we authenticate each API calls inside the framework ?

Do the API calls require session, like user authentication so that users can see and edit their account etc? Then all you need is `set_secure_cookie` method.
If the API calls are independent of each other, then you should let your users use your APIs with an "access key". You will need to store these access keys in a database. Your users will send this access key with every request, in the form of an HTTP header or just a request query parameter:

```
# as a header
API-Access-Key: <long-random-key>

# OR as a query string
http://yourserver.com?key=<long-random-key>
```